# I can’t find and solve the error, I’ve been stuck for 2 days and the new background is not applied

Tags: sass

// position fixed in order to escape the 1440px wrapper
.contact
position: fixed
top: 0
left: 0
width: 100%
height: 100%
background:
image: url("../img/contact-visual.png")
position: center
size: cover
repeat: no-repeat

&--lockup
position: relative
display: flex
width: 900px
max-width: 75%
height: 100%
align-items: center
justify-content: flex-end
margin: 0 auto

```
@media (max-width: 1180px)
  max-width: 90%

@media (max-width: 767px)
  justify-content: center
```

.modal
padding: 45px 45px
text-align: center
background-color: $black
box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75)

```
  &--information

    p,
    a
      display: block
      margin: 14px 0
      text-decoration: none
      color: $white
      font-weight: 700

    p
      margin-top: 0

  &--options
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    list-style: none

    & > li
      width: 130px
      margin: 0 auto 25px auto

    li:nth-child(1)
      background-color: #1769ff

    li:nth-child(2)
      background-color: #ea4c89

    li:nth-child(3)
      margin-bottom: 0
      background-color: $highlight
      text-transform: uppercase

    a
      display: block
      width: 100%
      padding: 8px 0
      text-decoration: none
      color: $white
      font-weight: 700
```